# Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Interface' for service type 'Interface', or How to dependency inject IPublicClientApplicationBuilder'

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, maui

**Intro**
Hey all, I have an error I don't understand. I assume it has something to do with dependency injection of IPublicClientApplication.

**Context**

I have two classes, with matching services and views, in a .NET6 MAUI project.
The two classes are Login, and Homepage. They handle a login page, and a homepage.

The service class for my login needs to take two instances of IPublicClientApplication, to handle my login-flow. So, I create a constructor, with the interfaces, as seen below:

My LoginService class

```
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    private readonly IPublicClientApplication loginClient;
    private readonly IPublicClientApplication changePasswordClient;
    public LoginService(IPublicClientApplication loginClient, IPublicClientApplication changePassword)
    {
        this.loginClient = loginClient;
        this.changePasswordClient = changePassword;
    }
}
```

And in the homepageViewModel, I check for a token, in case the user is not logged in, it pushes a login-page onto the stack.

```
public partial class HomepageViewModel
{
    private readonly IHomepageRepository _homepageRepository;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public HomepageViewModel(IHomepageRepository homepageRepository, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _homepageRepository = homepageRepository;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

        if(App.Token == null)
        {
            Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(_serviceProvider.GetService<Login>());
        }
    }   
}
```

The DI of the classes is handled in the MauiProgram.cs, as seen below.

```
        //Homepage
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<HomepageViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHomepageRepository, HomepageRepository>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<Homepage>();

        //Login
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoginService, LoginService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<Login>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IPublicClientApplication>();
```

**Error**

I included the error below. It originates in MauiProgram.cs, after adding singletons for the classes.
[image: Image of the error, in MauiProgram.cs]

**Question**

How do I mitigate this error? What is the best way to use a constructor in my service-class, while still getting the interfaces I require?

**Update**

I have updated the code, to add DI for the following interfaces:

```
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPublicClientApplication, PublicClientApplication>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoginService>(_ => new LoginService());
```

The last line is my problem. How would this look, if I added it with parameters?

Comment: The error is about `IPublicClientApplication`. You're registering an interface, without providing an implementation. Do the latter, just like you do for `<ILoginService, LoginService>` and `<IHomepageRepository, HomepageRepository>`.

Comment: You are not registering the implementing type of `IPublicClientApplication` interface. The DI can not create an instance of an interface. That's for obvious reason. So you need to register `IPublicClientApplication` along with its implementation in DI Container.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your feedback. I updated the question, with new code. With the implementation that I have now, I needed to add a singleton for the service as well, that took a new LoginService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting services in your constructor that are responsible for different things, but the requested types do not reflect those responsibilities. Therefore I think there is a flaw in the design of your interfaces.

I don't know anything about your application or MAUI, but I would expect the constructor signature to be something like this:

```
public LoginService(ILoginClient loginClient, IPasswordClient passwordClient)
{
    // ...
}
```

If your `PublicClientApplication` class is really responsible for both, you would let it implement both `ILoginClient` and `IPasswordClient`.

You could use `PublicClientApplication` as a singleton and register it like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<PublicClientApplication>();
services.AddSingleton<ILoginClient>(p => p.GetRequiredService<PublicClientApplication>());
services.AddSingleton<IPasswordClient>(p => p.GetRequiredService<PublicClientApplication>());
services.AddSingleton<LoginService>();
```

If the `IPublicClientApplication` interface is really responsible for login and password actions, than injecting it once would be enough, instead of two parameters.